# GRPC JsonTranscoding + gRPC web in Blazor WASM

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, blazor-webassembly, grpc-web, .net-8.0

It seems that Blazor WASM does not allow a reference to a project having 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Grpc.JsonTranscoding' installed. So my question is: (how) can GRPC JsonTranscoding and gRPC web be combined?

Some context:

I have a gRPC API with HTTP support using gRPC JSON trancoding in .NET 8.
My proto files are in a seperate project which references 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Grpc.JsonTranscoding Version="8.0.0-preview.7.'
Now I try to create a Blazor WASM project that references the proto project, but I get the following error:

`'There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.'`

Which I think indicates that this package is not supported in Blazor WASM. When I remove the gRPC JSON Transcoding package in the proto project the error is gone.